# File exists but System cannot find file specified is returned in cmd

Tags: windows-7, linux

I have an external disk and i have some files in folder.
I am able to copy files from other folders of the disk except one folder.
The command prompt autocompletes and shows absolute path of filename but does not copy and instead returns error "The System File could not be Found".

Also the Windows Explorer shows size in window but in properties the size and create/access time attributes are missing.

Please see the Stackoverflow question for images using the following link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497059/file-exists-but-system-cannot-find-file-specified-is-returned-in-cmd

I have also tried copying on linux as well but the file was not being copied

Can anyone suggest a way to copy these files to another location in either windows or linux?

Comment: your size file is 0, so maybe it's corrupted ?!

Comment: This usually indicates an issue with consistency between the filesystem and the disk, potentially because of damage to the disks surface, or the data. First, check your SMART stats to make sure the drive is healthy, and then run `chkdsk /f` on the drive. In windows, I use speedfan to read SMART data, and in linux, palimsest/Gnome Disks. pay particular attention to reallocated sector count, and current pending sector count. those indicate bad blocks on the disk, which often precedes total failure. if the disk is not healthy, get the files you can off it asap.

Comment: Why is this tagged "linux"? Do a chkdsk / fsck / filesystem check (as Frank advises)? Whats the filesystem type anyway?